Passing components instance from MainView to tab contents component in separate java class file
I was trying to pass two SvgIcon from MainView to separate Java class file which are tab contents, so I could change the icon but I couldn't find the element implementing a function like this:
public SvgIcon getSvgIcon(String classSvgIcon) {
    return (SvgIcon) CurrentInstance.get(SvgIcon.class).findAncestor(SvgIcon.class).hasClassName(classSvgIcon);
} 

because I supposed it should return me the SvgIcon element that corresponds to the class name contained in the element, even if I'd prefer the ID but I see there is no hasIdAttribute() function but it didn't worked...
so then I tried to pass the MainView UI class to access directly to the component I want to change, like this:
public static MainView getCurrent() {
    return (MainView) CurrentInstance.get(UI.class);
}

but even if in the tab content class I can call now MainView.getCurrent().myIconElement but in the function it says Cannot cast from UI to MainView... how it should be rewritten correctly that function so I could access to that svg icon I want to change?
Thanks in advance to all!
Cheers!
[EDIT]
There is my sample I'm trying to implement to change icon...
/* ************************************************************ 
 *                                                            *
 *          MainView class                                    *
 *                                                            *
 ************************************************************ */
package com.myexample.application.views.main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.UI;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.NativeLabel;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.Icon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.SvgIcon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.VaadinIcon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.FlexComponent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tab;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.TabsVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.internal.CurrentInstance;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterObserver;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.HighlightConditions;

import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouterLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouterLink;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.StreamResource;

@PageTitle("Main")
@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout, BeforeEnterObserver {

    private Map<Tab, RouterLink> tabSheets = new HashMap<>();
    private Tabs mainTabs; 

    private HorizontalLayout toolbar;       
    private NativeLabel appname;
    public SvgIcon iconToChange;

    public MainView() {
        
        RouteTabs tabsToAdd = new RouteTabs();
        tabsToAdd.addTab(new RouterLink("Tab 1", MyTab1.class), VaadinIcon.EYE.create());
        tabsToAdd.addTab(new RouterLink("Tab 2", MyTab2.class), VaadinIcon.EYE.create());
        
        add(getToolbar(), tabsToAdd);               
    }
    
    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        if (event.getNavigationTarget() == MainView.class) {
            event.forwardTo(MyTab1.class);
        }       
    }    

    public static MainView getCurrent() {
        return (MainView) CurrentInstance.get(UI.class).getCurrent();       
        //return CurrentInstance.get(UI.class);
        //return UI.getCurrent();
    }    
    
    public SvgIcon getIconToChange() { return (SvgIcon) iconToChange; }
    
    private HorizontalLayout getToolbar() {                     
        
        HorizontalLayout leftLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        
        appname = new NativeLabel("My Test");
        appname.setClassName("title-style");
        
        leftLayout.add(appname);
        leftLayout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.START);
        leftLayout.setWidth("100%");
                
        HorizontalLayout rightLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        
        StreamResource svgIconResource = new StreamResource("myOff_Icon.svg",
                () -> getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/myOff_Icon.svg"));
        svgIconResource.setCacheTime(0);        
        iconToChange = new SvgIcon(svgIconResource);
        iconToChange.addClassName("iconToChange");
        iconToChange.setId("iconToChange");
        iconToChange.setTooltipText("IconToChange");
        
        rightLayout.add(iconToChange);
        rightLayout.setJustifyContentMode(FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.END);
        rightLayout.setWidth("100%");

        var toolbar = new HorizontalLayout(leftLayout, rightLayout);
        toolbar.setWidthFull();
        toolbar.addClassName("toolbar");      
                
        return toolbar;
    }    
    
    
    private static class RouteTabs extends Tabs implements BeforeEnterObserver {
        private final Map<RouterLink, Tab> routerLinkTabMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        public void addTab(RouterLink routerLink, Icon iconToAdd) {
            routerLink.setHighlightCondition(HighlightConditions.sameLocation());
            routerLink.setHighlightAction(
                (link, shouldHighlight) -> {
                    if (shouldHighlight) setSelectedTab(routerLinkTabMap.get(routerLink));
                }             
            );            
            routerLinkTabMap.put(routerLink, new Tab(iconToAdd, routerLink));
            add(routerLinkTabMap.get(routerLink));
            this.addThemeVariants(TabsVariant.LUMO_EQUAL_WIDTH_TABS);
            this.setMaxWidth("100%");
            this.setWidthFull();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
            // In case no tabs will match
            setSelectedTab(null);
        }
    }
    
    /*public SvgIcon getSvgIcon(String idSvgIcon) {
        //return (SvgIcon) CurrentInstance.get(SvgIcon.class).equals(getElement().getAttribute("id").equals(idSvgIcon));
        //return (SvgIcon) CurrentInstance.get(SvgIcon.class).findAncestor(SvgIcon.class).hasClassName(idSvgIcon);
        return (SvgIcon) CurrentInstance.get(SvgIcon.class).getElement().hasAttribute("id");
    } */
    
}

/* ************************************************************ 
 *                                                            *
 *          MainView class                                    *
 *                                                            *
 ************************************************************ */
 
 
/* ************************************************************ 
 *                                                            *
 *          MyTab1.class class                                *
 *                                                            *
 ************************************************************ */
 
 package com.myexample.application.views.main;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Text;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.SvgIcon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.StreamResource;

@Route(value="mytab1", layout = MainView.class)
public class MyTab1 extends VerticalLayout {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private SvgIcon iconChangeTo;
    private Text localText;
    private Button localButton;
        
    public ARDevices() {                    
        localText = new Text("My Tab 1");
            
        localButton = new Button("Change Icon");
        localButton.addClickListener(e -> {
            //iconChangeTo = Element.getAttribute("id").
            //iconChangeTo = UI.getCurrent().navigate(SvgIcon.class).ifPresent(icon -> icon.hasClassName("iconToChange")).      
            
            //SvgIcon icon = ((MainView) MainView.getCurrent()).getIconToChange();
            //MainView.getCurrent()

            SvgIcon icon = MainView.getCurrent().getIconToChange()
            
            
            //UIclass.iconToChange.setSrc( new StreamResource("myON_Icon.svg",
            //  () -> getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/myON_Icon.svg")) );
        });
                
        add(localText, localButton);
    }   
}
/* ************************************************************ 
 *                                                            *
 *          MyTab1.class class                                *
 *                                                            *
 ************************************************************ */


In case this is an X-Y-problem, could you please explain what you want
to do?  E.g. why not pass the container for the icon or a consumer
function down to the tab on creation so it change the icon?

HI @cfrick , first thank you for your answer, I have created in MainView a toolbar where there is just a SvgIcon  which has to be just white (off) or green (on). I tried earlier to pass just the svgicon itself via Route as parameter to the tab content class but after some trying it looked it seems not possible to pass via Route. So I thought to make available the MainView UI so I could access directly to the svgicon or at least to reach a public return function in MainView where I pass the SvgIcon but it doesn't....

And "MainView" is a RouterLayout?  So you have a single icon on multiple routes shared via a central layout and something wants to change the class/color/... of this icon? So you want to find the router layout and the icon therein?

hello again @cfrick , I just updated my post with the sample I am implementing where you can see I have this toolbar with an icon in MainView, and you can see I was trying to implement a method in MainView to let MyTab1 to access the MainView's class methods so I could just change the icon through that method... Maybe if there is a way to pass the icon via Route, how it can be done? Because I already tried that but since Route goes through an URL so I think it can't be passed just objects....maybe

@cfrick , thank you very much! In that answer you linked there is a reference to another post on Vaadin community which helped me to understand why I implemented wrong the getCurrent() function , so correcting it now it works! Thanks again @cfrick

There's three ways that I'm aware of to get the MainView instance from a child view.
First option is to get the current UI instance and find the mainView within its children:
MainView mainView = (MainView) UI.getCurrent().getChildren()
            .filter(component -> component.getClass() == MainView .class).findFirst().orElse(null);



Second option is similar but vice versa, you start at the child view and look upwards. It looks uglier since you can only get 1 parent at a time in contrast to getChildren which returns a filterable Stream. I'm also unsure if this works within the constructor of the child view:
MainView mainView = null;
Optional<Component> parentOpt = this.getParent(); // this == some child view
while(parentOpt.isPresent()) {
    Component parent = parentOpt.get();
    if(parent instanceof MainView) {
        mainView = (MainView) parent;
        parentOpt = Optional.empty(); // stop the loop
    } else {
        // look further
        parentOpt = parent.getParent();
    }
}


And finally the third option, which is what I use, but it requires dependency injection. In both the MainView as well as all possible child views that need it, we inject a MainViewBus (not so sure about the naming.. Find a better name for it if you can), which we can use to get the MainView directly. No HTML element child/parent crawling necessary here.
@Component
@UIScope
public class MainViewBus {
    private MainView mainView;

    public MainViewBus() {
    }

    public MainView getMainView() {
        return this.mainView;
    }
    public void setMainView(MainView mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
    }
}

public class MainView implements RouterLayout {
    public MainView(MainViewBus mainViewBus){
        mainViewBus.setMainView(this);
    }
    
    public void someMethod(){
        Notification.show("You just invoked a method on MainView from a child view.");
    }
}

@Route("foo", layout = MainView.class)
public class FooView extends VerticalLayout {
    public FooView(MainViewBus mainViewBus){
        add(new Button("Test MainView Bus", click -> mainViewBus.getMainView().someMethod()));
    }
}


Since I see @cfrick 's answer with the link to another answer , which there is the first option suggested by @kscherner , looks deleted I accept @kscherner 's answer due there is the correct getCurrent() I had to write in my code to obtain my goal. Thanks to both you anyway!
